# Nancy Dependency Injection register multiple

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nancy, tinyioc

I have a module which is expecting a dependency to be satisfied however I get the an error stating

**Something went wrong when trying to satisfy one of the dependencies during composition, make sure that you've registered all new dependencies in the container and inspect the innerexception for more details.**

The inner exception which I believe is a red herring:

**Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher
I believe I have hooked this up correctly (see below).**

```
public class FooModule : NancyModule
{
    private readonly SomeValidator validator;

    public FooModule(SomeValidator validator)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
        //CODE..
    }
}


public class Bootstrap : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        container.Register(new SomeValidator(new FooValidator()));

        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
    }
}   

public class SomeValidator
{
    private readonly IValidator[] validators;

    public SomeValidator(params IValidator[] validators)
    {
        this.validators = validators;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the SomeValidator like this:

```
container.Register<SomeValidator>(new SomeValidator(new FooValidator()));
```